# C++ - Saving & Deleting

Tags: c++, banking

I'm creating a sample banking programme for fun and I realised I needed some help.

I have it set so that you can create two different types of bank accounts - one for personal and one for a business. I want to be able to save the data given into these accounts & also be able to delete data if they account gets "cancelled" etc.

My idea was to have separate files be created for each account holder - so each person or company will have a file created with the data in it (how much money, name, etc.). Is this a realistic approach or would it just cluster up and take a lot of space? Is there an easier way of doing this? (more efficient or faster).

**Note:** I don't want a code for this question, I want an explanation on how to approach this problem the best.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: For a program that you are writing just for fun, using the filesystem seems reasonable. However, you might want to look into using a database to store your data. I would try MySql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with files.

However, eventually as the program becomes complex you'll end up needing more structure (like shared data between multiple accounts), atomicity (no intermediate state visible), transactions (being able to roll back some actions), more throughput, backups, reporting, aggregation, multi-system distribution, check-pointing, migrations and others. You can implement it on top of your file structure, but it's going to be hard.

Luckily there's already a simple solution. It's called a database. You can setup your own instance relatively easy and provides out of the box what you already need and a bunch of features that you didn't think you need right now, but likely you're going to need them at some point in the future.

So checkout a SQL database (like MySql, PostGreSQL, SQlite or some more advanced solutions from Microsoft or Oracle) or one of the NoSQL solutions offered by cloud providers (bigtable for example). At this point any of them is likely to satisfy your need to store, modify and delete data.

Comment: SQlite is probably worth suggesting too. That way the OP can avoid the need for a separate and heavyweight database application, whilst getting most of the benefits, and the ability to easily switch to a "real" database if and when needed.

Comment: I thought about files, but I also realised at some point you'll have a million files floating around and things can get messy. (Especially since I wanted to make the programme be able to change data and interact with the data). It's good to know that using files isn't the only way! 

I haven't done anything with databases yet in my OOP classes etc., but I'll look into it now. Also it's probably not bad having some background knowledge before the new semester starts. 

Thanks for the tip!